# Set minted/pygments language as text if the language isn't supported

Tags: minted, pygments

When I use minted/pygments to highlight code-blocks, if I have a code-block with `plantuml` language or `org` for Org-Mode in Emacs, the code-block becomes empty. Is it possible to tell minted/pygments to just use a text mode for the unsupported languages?

Note: As I'm exporting the latex from Emacs, all the code blocks have a language. The language might be unsupported but I have code-highlight in Emacs, so I just want to output the code even if it doesn't have code-highlighting.

Comment: See https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/274, under which I've added a new attempt and hope it helps.